# LDAP authentication throttling

Tags: java, spring, authentication, active-directory, ldap

We have a customer, which uses LDAP for most of the applications deployed in its Enterprise. Naturally, our product also uses same LDAP for authentication. While performing the authentication check (not using IWA), we are accepting username/password using form based interface. Later service queries LDAP using Spring `LDAPTemplate` to check if the provided credentials are valid. In case of invalid credentials, service internally maintains a count against the user id. If that count has cross the specified limit, it locks user and does not allow to login in our product.

While the failed count was implemented with the intention of throttling invalid attempts at Product level and there by ensuring LDAP account doesn't get locked (LDAP lock count could be higher). Hence even if the user gets locked in our product, with the legitimate credentials he can still continue with other apps. The situation may arise, if someone tries to login in our product using someone else's credentials.

Is this thought correct? OR we should get rid of locking feature at the product level and continue to make request to LDAP, till the account gets locked at LDAP?

**Scenario**

Organization XYZ Ltd. has LDAP which is used for Product A, Product B and also for Windows OS authentication. LDAP has login failure count as 15. There are two users Mr. P, Mr. Q.

**Locking at product level** (*Max login fail count is 5*)

1. Mr. Q, tries to login in Product A, using user id of Mr. P with incorrect password.
2. Mr. Q, tries 5 times and hence Mr. P's account is locked in product. LDAP login failure count is updated to 5.
3. Mr. P tries to login in Product A and he gets a message as Account is locked.
4. Mr. P has still access to Windows OS and he can still access other applications.

**No Locking at product level**

1. Mr. Q, tries to login in Product A, using user id of Mr. P with incorrect password.
2. Mr. Q, tries 15 times and hence Mr. P's account is locked in product. LDAP login failure count is updated to 15.
3. Mr. P tries to login in Product A and he gets a message as Account is locked.
4. Mr. P has no access to other applications.

With above scenario, which behavior will be acceptable? Product with/without locking support.

Comment: Which LDAP server are you using? The ones I'm familiar with can already do that via configuration with no coding required at all, anywhere, let alone at the product level.

Comment: Hi @EJP yes it does allow via configuration and most do the same. But my question is not about LDAPs capability. It is more about where to keep throttling of making request and locking user, in case of Enterprise LDAP. I agree there are plus/minuses of both approach, but want to understand which one will be more beneficial.

Comment: I can't think of one reason why you wouldn't just leave it all to the LDAP server. That's what it's for. It's there, it's done, it works, it's debugged, no code to write, nothing to maintain. I don't know why the question is even being asked.

Comment: Hey @EJP, you cant think of reason, but I already gave one in my post. I said LDAP is being shared across apps (and may be in domain controller). Hence if one of the application makes continuous requests with invalid userid/password, the requests will end up locking account, which may not be legitimate.

Comment: Why may that not be legitimate?